# Finding a Solution to the system of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find a solution $\Phi$ of the system
\begin{align*}
y_1'&=-y_1\\
y_2'&=y_1+y_2\\
\end{align*}

satisfying the initial condition $\Phi(0)=(2,1)$.

Thanks for the help. I found $y_1$ but cannot get $y_2$ to work correctly for $y'_2$.

I got $y_1=2 \Bbb e^{-t}$, but for $y_2$ I kept getting $(1+2t) \Bbb e ^{-t}$ which doesn't work because the derivative is $-y_1 -y_2$ instead of $y1 +y2$.

Comment: What methods did you learn for solving a system of linear, ordinary differential equations?

Comment: Can you write down your solution for $y_1$ and your attempt for $y_2$?

Answer (score 0):

You have $y_1 = 2 e^{-t}$, which is correct.  Then rearranging the equation for $y_2$ gives you 
\begin{align*}
y_2' - y_2 = 2 e^{-t}.
\end{align*}
Multiply the equation through by the integrating factor $e^{-t}$ and you get
\begin{align*}
( y_2 e^{-t} )' = 2 e^{-2t}.
\end{align*}
Integrate the above expression from $0$ to $t$ and use the initial condition $y_2(0) = 1$ to arrive at 
\begin{align*}
y_2(t) e^{-t} - 1 = \int_0^t 2 e^{-2s} ds = - e^{-2s}|_0^t = 1 - e^{-2t}.
\end{align*}
Thus, you arrive at (after simplifying)
\begin{align*}
y_2(t) = 2 e^t - e^{-t}.
\end{align*}
You can now check to see that $y_1$ and $y_2$ satisfy your given system.

Comment: how does that solve y2' = y1 +y2 because if you plug it in it doesn't work for the second equation.

Comment: It does work.  y_2' = 2 e^t + e^{-t}.  y_1 + y_2 = 2 e^{-t} + (2 e^t - e^{-t}) = 2e^t + e^{-t}. Thus, y_2' = y_1 + y_2.